# Parallel Updating Partitioned table in Oracle via Spring Batch

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, spring-batch

I have a table in Oracle with:

- 500,000,000 records
- and 109 fields

I Partitioned the table by range as follow:

```
create table AC.MY_DEAL
(
REFERENCE                  VARCHAR2(20) not null,
EXTERNAL_REFERENCE         VARCHAR2(20),
BOOK_DATE                  DATE not null,
blah blah blah...
)
partition by range (BOOK_DATE)(
partition DEAL_01 values less than (TO_DATE('01/31/2012','MM/DD/YYYY')), --January
partition DEAL_02 values less than (TO_DATE('02/31/2012','MM/DD/YYYY')), --February
blah blah blah... for other months
partition DEAL_12 values less than (TO_DATE('02/31/2012','MM/DD/YYYY')), --December
);
alter table AC.MY_DEAL add constraint PK_MY_DEAL primary key (REFERENCE); -- Primary Key
create index IX_MY_DEAL on AC.MY_DEAL (BOOK_DATE) local;                  -- Partition Key
```

> **Now I want to write a SPRING BATCH code that updates one field of
>   all 12 partitions of the table in parallel.**

Can anyone help me to find out how can I update these partitions in parallel with spring batch?

I wrote one but I assume that it still updates the partitions one by one - not parallel. If you want to see my Spring Batch config I can add them too.

Thanks In Advance :)

Comment: `lab lab lab.` : I am confused. It didn't had to be `bla bla bla`? :) (just kidding)

Comment: Your partition definitions are strange. "less than (TO_DATE('01/31/2012','MM/DD/YYYY'))" is dates prior to the last day of January 2012, so you probably want (in ANSI syntax) "less than (date '2012-01-01'". You probably want to give that partition a name like "Y2012M01", also. That index on your partition key column could be LOCAL also, and if you are inserting in bulk data sets through a single process consider using a BITMAP index.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Yes, I have 500KK records and it will become larger too :). But about my partitioning definitions you are right but the first record of the table is inserted in the first day of January. So the first partition holds data of just one month.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Can you tell me more about why should I using BITMAP index?

Comment: @FlorinGhita I correct it :)

Comment: Bitmap indexes are more compact, and more useful for multicolumn predicates in which multiple indexes have to be efficiently combined together. However they're not suitable where you have multiple sessions modifying the table or very high cardinalities that approach uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best choice here would be to review the Parallel DML documentation for the appropriate version of Oracle: eg. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/usingpe.htm

In general you'll need to enable parallel DML in your transaction, and configure the server's parallel query parameters.

There is also a useful section in there on monitoring parallel DML.